# Изменение языка через нажатие на кнопку, Android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Есть приложение, в нём есть кнопка "Язык", и я хочу, чтобы по нажатии на кнопку выскакивала менюшка с выбором языка. Как это реализовать? Перевёл string.xml в нужные мне языки, но не могу реализовать выбор языка. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается это так:

1) В ресурсах (**res/**) проекта должны быть папки со значениями для разных языков. Например для русского и английского соответственно: **values-ru**, **values-en**.

2) Далее при нажатии на кнопку выбора вам надо задать языковую локаль приложению. Пример кода [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android), выданный на запрос гуглу

> [quick language switch android programmatically](https://www.google.ru/search?q=quick+language+switch+android+programmatically&oq=quick+language+switch+android+programmatically&aqs=chrome..69i57.345j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(КОД_ЯЗЫКА_НАПРИМЕР_RU.toLowerCase());
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```